# Rails cart with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paypal, cart

I've made a basic cart for my web app, I'm just having a hard time thinking of how to bridge the gap to making a payment.  I got the cart from [Ryan Bates's RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics) and am using his PayPal methods as well.  I'm using Devise to handle authentication.

Before a user is allowed to hit 'checkout', they need to be logged in (so I know who bought what).

Ryan just has the checkout link go directly to paypal.  I can only allow the checkout link to go to paypal if the user has logged on.

Do I need to make another model & controller (maybe invoice?) and do a before :authenticate_user! on a method in invoice and then have the checkout link actually link_to the invoice controller?  Will taht actually direct a user to sign-in/up, then upon completion send the user to paypal?

I'm trying to make the flow so that a user only has to click "check out" once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a new action in my cart called `checkout` and setting calling

```
 before_filter :authorize_user!, only: [:checkout]
```

Then Devise takes off.

Maybe obvious, but I definitely had to think about it.